# Geo centroid aggregation geo distance sort in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

In a query I used geo centroid aggregation. So I have a latitude, longitude for each bucket. Now I want so sort the buckets based on the geo distance from a given location which is also a latitude, longitude .

Some one please help me how to do it. Because aggregation is not accepting sort. it only accepts order.